# TYPO3 Specific URL for successfully sent form

Tags: typo3, typo3-form

Using TYPO3 10 LTS, I have a contact form at https://example.com/contacts

I use the "Confirmation finisher" that has the same url https://example.com/contacts with some query string and post.

I needed another specific URL for when the form has been submitted successfully so I used this route enhancer:

```
routeEnhancers:
  ContactForm:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Form
    plugin: Formframework
    routes:
      - routePath: '/submit'
        _controller: 'FormFrontend::perform'
    defaultController: 'FormFrontend::perform'
```

Now the URL of a submitted form is: https://example.com/contacts/submit

The problem is that this URL appears even if the form has error (eg.: captcha error) so it's not really finished.

Is there a way to have a specific URL only when the form is submitted successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Redirect` finisher](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/11.5/en-us/I/Config/proto/finishersDefinition/finishers/Redirect.html) in your form definition.

This will only be triggered upon successful submit and you will have a different URL in the end.

As bonus you also prevent re-submit by reload this way.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, this could be a viable solution but is there a way to achieve the same result without creating another page? I ask this because it's better to manage the "thank you" message in the same page as where the form is because it's easier to handle translation and display other content like the map in common with form page.

Comment: If the form must be fully generated from code, yes. But usually there is a demand for editors to adjust the success page by editing in the backend. You _will_ need a redirect in one way or another since the request URL cannot be affected by the form result any other way.